# How can I remove #N/A from macro results / also multiple lookups using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have been trying to put together a spread sheet to track down several activities using some macros I got from different places as I can’t write my own

I have 2 problems:

1. This macro does a lookup from one sheet and returns a value in another

   ```
        Dim lngLastRow As Long
        Dim wsOutput   As Worksheet
        Dim wsSource   As Worksheet

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set wsOutput = Sheets("sheet 1") 'Sheet name for the following VBA to fill in
        Set wsSource = Sheets("sheet 2") 'Sheet name containing completed data for VLOOKUP

        lngLastRow = wsOutput.Range("A:G").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        With wsOutput

            With .Range("B2:B" & lngLastRow)
                .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!A:G,6,FALSE)"
                .Value = .Value 'Convert above formula to a value.  Comment out or remove if you want the formula to remain
         End With
        End With

        Set wsOutput = Nothing
        Set wsSource = Nothing

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
   ```

So I do a lookup from column C in sheet 1 in a table in sheet 2.

The macro does the look up and returns values in column B  in sheet 1.
The macro does that for all values in column C in sheet 1.

Problem: if no value found it returns #N/A, how do I get rid of that, I don't know how to use `iferror` in VBA

2. I am using the same macro to do the same exact thing but for 2 other sheets, and its behaving differently. This time I am looking up column A in sheet 1, in sheet 2.

Problem 1: It's not working ! It only does the look up for the first value in column a and does not  go through all the values in column a, as I have no clue what I am doing I tried to change the value in the “with. Range”  part, it fixed the issue, but now it seems like it's trying to do the lookup for 300 cells down when there are only 17 cells with values in the lookup column

I realize what I am saying probably makes no sense, so I have attached the workbook

https://easyupload.io/eehkw8

Column C has the with.range set as C2:C, and the problem is that it does not do lookup for the entire column

Column D has the with.range set as D30:D, and the problem here is that it does the lookup even if there is no Value to lookup, it also adds #N/A

Edit adding second macro

```
Option Explicit

Sub update_Co1newincidents()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim wsOutput   As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource   As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("New tickets") 'Sheet name for the following VBA to fill in
    Set wsSource = Sheets("lookup") 'Sheet name containing completed data for VLOOKUP

    lngLastRow = wsOutput.Range("C:W").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    With wsOutput
        'Formula for School Name
        With .Range("C2:C" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!C:W,3,FALSE)"
            .Value = .Value 'Convert above formula to a value.  Comment out or remove if you want the formula to remain
            
            
     End With
    End With
    
    With wsOutput
        'Formula for School Name
        With .Range("D2:D30" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!C:W,4,FALSE)"
            .Value = .Value 'Convert above formula to a value.  Comment out or remove if you want the formula to remain
            
            
     End With
    End With
    
                  
    Set wsOutput = Nothing
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[This is a mock up of the sheet that is supposed to have to lookup output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxNMb.png)

Comment: Checkout `IsError(.Value)` it returns `True` if the value in the cell is an error. So if there is an error you can eg. use `.Value = ""` and if no error then convert `.Value = .Value`. • Please also include some example data or a screenshot. It is very unlikely that anyone here will download something from a suspect source. • Note that you can investigate your code step by step using `F8` and check the values of your variables in each step. This way you can find out where it goes wrong. Figure out wher exactly the issue is and precise your question (it is too broad to give a proper answer).

Comment: thank you for your response ,i will make sure to do so , didn't know about f8 this is very useful, i tried it , i am am not really getting an error , it is just i have the macro not working as i  want , i have updated the post with more information

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the result to be #N/A. If so, return empty string, otherwise return the lookup value.

   `.Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!A:G,6,FALSE)), """", VLOOKUP(C2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!A:G,6,FALSE))"`
2. <strike>Maybe the the resulting reference "'lookup'!" is not correct, while there's no space character in the sheet's name "lookup". Try removing the single quotes. Does that help?</strike>

   `.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "!C:W,3,FALSE)"`

   For the first formula I still have no solution. But for the second:

   You say you want to use the cells D30:D for the next formula. So you should use the value in A30 I guess. Then I think the following should be changed:

   `.Range("D2:D30" & lngLastRow)
   .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!C:W,4,FALSE)"`

   into

   `.Range("D30:D" & lngLastRow)
   .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A30,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!C:W,4,FALSE)"`

Comment: Thanks Gert , the ISNA works !   , i have added the second macro in the original post

Comment: Or you could use `IFERROR`:  `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'" & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "'!C:W,3,FALSE),"""")"`

Comment: i dont have single quotes in the macro

Comment: i tried .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & CStr(wsSource.Name) & "!C:W,3,FALSE)" without the quotes  , no luck